# Adding entries to a java directory

Tags: java, directory

I have a project due for my java programming class. The program is to create a directory that keeps track of students, faculty, and staff. The project is completed, however my professor wants us to have some entries already there (so he doesn't have to type them all in). Since it is finished I'm a bit unsure of how to go about adding these. I've been told I can read/write a file and add it to my treemap but I'm not sure how. I've also been told I can just add some in the constructor. Can anyone help me with this? The code for the directory part of the project is below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Directory {
static Map<String, Person> schoolDirectory = new TreeMap<>();

static public void addPerson(final Person person) {
    if (person != null)
        schoolDirectory.put(person.getKey(), person);
}

static Person removePerson(final String key) {
    return schoolDirectory.remove(key);
}

static Person retrievePerson(final String key) {
    return schoolDirectory.get(key);
}

static Iterator<Person> getMemberInformation(Predicate filter) {
   List<Person> members = new ArrayList<Person>();
    if (schoolDirectory.size() > 0) {
        for (Person person : schoolDirectory.values()) {
            if(filter.test(person))
                members.add(person);            }
        return members.iterator();
    }
    return null;
}

static Map<String, Person> getFilingSystem() {
    return new TreeMap<>(schoolDirectory);
}

static void setFilingSystem(Map<String, Person> data) {
    schoolDirectory = data;
}

static void loadDirectory(){
    Database.restore();
}
}
```

Comment: "Can anyone help me with this?" is a very poor question. What part is not working?

Comment: It's all working, I just cannot figure out how to add information into the directory so it is there when the program is started, rather than having to manually add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a constructor, now your constructor is a default constructor that does kinda nothing(read more about constructors).

```
    public Directory(){
        //add whatever you want
    }
```

what ever you put in this constructor method, will happen every time you initialise a new Directory object,for example:

```
    Directory tree = new Directory()
```

so every new Directory object will always be initialised with the same default data

Hope it helps